# python crawler stalled with no warning or error

Tags: python

my code are here:
https://gist.github.com/3834860

it will stall after run for a while,the output like following:

```
2012-10-05 00:42:31,932 - DEBUG - next_url ishttp://m.tianya.cn/bbs/list.jsp?item=free&p=4&n=2012-10-05 00:41:23.213&idwriter=0&key=0&chk=&vu=49368951554
2012-10-05 00:42:33,914 - DEBUG - ['2366245', '2800363', '2698574', '2797207', '2801356', '2212342', '2216658', '2799029', '2747949', '2801410', '2562954', '2800201', '2188615', '2801369', '2800497', '2800402', '2731162', '2801265', '2800437', '2799819']
2012-10-05 00:42:34,462 - DEBUG - next_url ishttp://m.tianya.cn/bbs/list.jsp?item=free&p=5&n=2012-10-05 00:41:23.213&idwriter=0&key=0&chk=&vu=49368954180
```

and it just stall there,no warning or error,i can't debug it,because it will stall after 1 hour later.

I don't know how to debug it,anyone can tell me?

Comment: put more debug print statements in to try and try and nail down exactly where your problem is ... maybe its the website you are calling? does it just happen with one? (If i had to guess its probably choking on some chinese characters)

Comment: I want to print the 'wrong message',but I don't know how,and maybe because of the website,so I want to know how to figure what's the problem? how to figure out?

Comment: I should add a timeout to the code,you give me a hint,thx

Comment: You can use eclipse and put a breakepoint after 1 hour if this is what you need. But I would start with what @JoranBeasley suggested.

Comment: It could be that you internet connection is poor, try putting more debug statements to try to debug it